# Vuejs Modal. Avoid changing props, nuxt.js iview

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, nuxt.js, iview-ui

I need help with modals, i tried to get this question sorted yesterday but then it got even worse. So please any help would be appreciated.
I have a parent component and inside of there i have a modal (child component)

In my parent the code:

```
    <template>
<div class="all">
  <Button type="primary" @click="modalUp()">Press me</Button>
  <appTest @changed = "modal1 = $event" :modal1='modal1'> </appTest>
  {{modal1}}

</div>
</template>
<script>
/* eslint-disable */
import test from '~components/test.vue'


export default {

  data(){
    return{
     modal1: false
    }
  },
  components: {
    appTest: test
  },
  methods: {
    modalUp() {
      this.modal1 = true
    }
  },
  watch:{
    modal1: function(){
      this.$on('changed', (data)=>{

        console.log(data)
      })

    }
  }

}

</script>
<style lang="css" scoped>


</style>
```

inside of the child component (appTest) i have this

```
 <template>
 <div id="" >
   <Modal v-model="modal1" title="MODALLLL" @on-ok="ok" @on-cancel="cancel">
     <p>@twitter</p>
     <p>@facebook</p>
     <p>Good</p>
     {{modal1}}
   </Modal>
 </div>
 </template>
 <script>
 /* eslint-disable */
 export default {
   props: ['modal1'],
   data() {
     return {
     }
   },
   methods: {
     ok() {
       this.$Message.info('all good');

     },
     cancel() {
       this.$Message.info('Cancel');
       this.$emit('changed')
     }
   },
   watch:{
     modal1: function(){
       this.$emit('changed', this.modal1)
     }
   }

 }
 </script>
 <style lang="css" scoped>
 </style>
```

So this code works in one way, the modal shows up correctly but once its gone and when we get back to parent component it gives me this vue warning AVOID MUTATING PROP

I checked the docs and everything but vuejs docs give examples like 2+2 which is not helpful in this case. I watched videos on the internet etc but still don't know how to get it done in a proper way.

What would be the best way to get it working?

I'm using modal from iview

Comment: Do you really have `this.modal1 = console.log(data)` in your watcher? Also, don't set up event handlers in a watcher, you're going to add a new event handler every time the value changes.

Comment: ahw no :) i forgot to remove it, it was meant to be false but in either way it doesnt work in the way i need anyway. So if u got any suggestions please share :)

Comment: I expect the problem is `v-model="modal1"` in the child component. I don't know what `Modal` is, but `v-model` will attempt to change the bound value and `modal1` is a property.

Comment: i tried to remove it and change it around but it doesnt work. The interesting thing is that when i open the modal the value sets to true, but if i close it the value becomes undefined. I tried to do if(this.modal1===undefined) but still apparently im not that smart to get around it :)

Comment: What is `Modal`? It looks like a global component.

Comment: https://github.com/iview/iview/blob/2.0/src/components/modal/modal.vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149328/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-stan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your child to use a computed value.

```
export default {
  props: ['modal1'],
  computed:{
    showModal:{
      get(){return this.modal1},
      set(v){ this.$emit("changed", v)}
    }
  },
}
```

And update the child template to

```
<Modal v-model="showModal" ...></Modal>
```

Doing this, whever you change `modal1` in the parent, the value will be updated in the `Modal` component, and whenever the `Modal` component changes the value, it will be sent to the parent.